# Postman is giving 401 instead of 403 on Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth

With this code:

**MyAuthorizationServerProvider**

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated(); // 
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Juan Dela Cruz"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Barok Kabundukan"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username or password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthorizeAttribute**

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
    else
    {
        actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //enable cors origin requests
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        var myProvider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = myProvider
        };
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
}
```

**DataController**

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/data/forall")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Server time is: " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/data/authenticate")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetForAuthenticate()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        return Ok("Hello " + identity.Name);
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/data/authorize")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetForAdmin()
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var roles = identity.Claims
                    .Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)
                    .Select(c => c.Value);
        return Ok("Hello " + identity.Name + " Role: " + string.Join(",", roles.ToList()));
    }
}
```

With that code, I am able to get the token and authenticate. The problem however is when I use the "user" credentials and authenticate then access the method that has Authorize(Role="admin"), in the Postman, I get "401". I should be getting the "403" since I am authenticated already but do not have a role of "admin". Can you please show me where I am getting it wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No, you should still get 401. 401 means unauthorized, not unauthenticated. In your scenario, you do not have the admin role, so you are not authorized to access the requested resource.

EDIT:
I don't usually post Wikipedia, but I think the article on 403 explains this pretty well; see the section on the differences between 401 and 403:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: When I use the user credentials, I get authenticated. And when I try to acces the method that has the admin role, I get the 401. I should get the 403, meaning I should be forbidden since I am just logged in but not as an admin.

Comment: Please look at the posted wikipedia link or any references in it. In your scenario, you still should get 401 based on the IETF standards, and that's how it is implemented with ASP.NET Identity.